# How to right align numbers in the center of a table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, alignment

Given a table with a column that contains numbers, I'd like to position them in the center.

But, I'd like to **right-align the numbers** as well!

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18923538273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9823</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Outputs:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

**Note:** The table cell width should be constant (200px), regardless of the numbers. For example, if all numbers are 0, they all should be in the center of the table:

[image]

**Also:**

- You are allowed to modify the content of the `<td>`s, but there should be one number per `<tr>`.
- CSS only, please.

Comment: May I ask why you removed your accept?

Comment: I just noticed your update, _...but there should be one number per `<tr>`_, and I guess that's why you removed the accept. Along with a few more of your comments, that pretty much invalidated my answer, ... I'm working on an update and will post it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated based on an edit of the question and a few comments*

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150053/how-to-right-align-numbers-in-the-center-of-a-table-cell#comment81249904_47150103) you wrote *"In the desired outcome, the cell width stays the same (200px) as numbers change"*.

In [another comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39913205#39913205) you wrote *"...my numbers are links and I want them to occupy the full cell width"*.

Given those requirements, the only CSS based solution I can find is, where one use `CSS Table` instead of `<table>` elements, an anchor `a` element displayed as `table-row`, making the full width clickable without adding an event handler, and for the centering, using pseudo elements to puch the *numbers* to the middle.

Stack snippet

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.tr span {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
}
a.tr {
  text-align: right;
}
.tr::before, .tr::after {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="thead">
    <span class="tr">
      <span>Amount</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <a href="#1" class="tr">
      <span>45</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#2" class="tr">
      <span>2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#3" class="tr">
      <span>18923538273</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#4" class="tr">
      <span>9823</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="thead">
    <span class="tr">
      <span>Amount</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <a href="#1" class="tr">
      <span>0</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#2" class="tr">
      <span>0</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#3" class="tr">
      <span>0</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#4" class="tr">
      <span>0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_____________________________________________________________________________**

*This is my first answer, which I will leave, as there might be someone that can make use of it as is.*

One simple way to accomplish that is to simply nest a `table` for the values, center it using auto margin and right align its `td`'s content.

This way you will get pretty much the exact same behavior as with your original markup, but get a better control of the values alignment.

Stack snippet

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

table table {
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table table td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>45</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>18923538273</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9823</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

You can of course use `div`'s instead of a `table`, displayed as inline block or inline flex column.

Inline block

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

td > div > div {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>45</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>18923538273</div>
          <div>9823</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>0</div>
          <div>0</div>
          <div>0</div>
          <div>0</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Inline flex column

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td > div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

td > div > div {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>45</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>18923538273</div>
          <div>9823</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>0</div>
          <div>0</div>
          <div>0</div>
          <div>0</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
td {
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 10px;
}
td:first-child, td:last-child {
  width: 50%;
}
```

... and adding an extra column before and after the existing one. jsFiddle [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/e0w3d2fq/).

---

*Initial answer:*

Considering your markup,

```css
td {
  text-align: right;
  border-left:7rem solid transparent;
  border-right:7rem solid transparent;
}
```

... should do it.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
  border-left:7rem solid transparent;
  border-right:7rem solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18923538273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9823</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<strike>Any other solution involves changing the markup (you need to add inner elements inside `<td>`s, give them smaller width than the `<td>`, and right align their text). You can do it by modifying the HTML source or on the fly, using JavaScript.</strike>

---

After a good number of tries, the only reliable solution I found (implying markup modification and no JavaScript), was to add  additional columns in the table, relying on the table's ability to line up all the cells in a column.

I updated the snippet below so that the column occupies the minimum necessary width, based on most wide number and right-aligns all cells based on resulting width width. This means that when all values are 0, the entire row of values are centered. Here it is:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
td {
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 10px;
}
td:first-child, td:last-child {
  width: 50%;
}


/* just stacking tables side by side, not part of solution */
table {      
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
body { overflow-y: hidden;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>2</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>0</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>1234</td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>2</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>1</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>4</td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>0</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>1155</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>1234548775564</td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is interesting. The only problem with your solution is that the cell width is changing with the numbers. In the desired outcome, the cell width stays the same (200px) as numbers change.

Comment: As added in the answer, your only alternative is to add a child element to each `<td>` and control its width and text-alignment.

Comment: Could you demonstrate your idea of modifying the content of `<td>` (using CSS only)?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko... actually, if we use `border` instead of `padding`, I think it works as intended. Updating...

Comment: @Misha. Updated answer. I assume this is what you wanted. If not, I'm need a working example, to understand your problem.

Comment: Interesting try :) Now, the problem is that the alignment depends on the header (the word "Amount"). Try, for example, to change all the numbers to 0. You'll see that the numbers are not in the middle of the table anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158370/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-misha-moroshko).

Answer (score 0):

make `text-align:right` and `padding-right:5em`in td css selector

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 4em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18923538273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9823</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your solution, the table cell width is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
table {
border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
width: 200px;
}
td {
text-align: center;
float:right; <!--added this-->
margin-right:50px; <!-- and this-->
}
</style>
```

I added float:right in td 
adjust the margin-right value to your desired value;

Comment: This solution is not dynamic. It depends on the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the display property for `td` elements to `block`

You can then set a `max-width` to bring `td` elements to the center of `tr` elements.

Once that's done you set the `text-align` property to `right` for `td` elements to make the numbers start from the right hand side.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  display: block;
  max-width: 70%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18923538273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9823</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it's not dynamic. You have to hard code the `max-width` value based on the numbers involved. Try in your example to change 18923538273 to 0, and you'll see that `max-width: 70%` is not that great anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your numbers with element(`span`) inside the `td` and add the text align right styles on it.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td span {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
  background: beige;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>45</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>18923538273</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>9823</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your outcome is different from the desired outcome.

Comment: You can add that 200px for the 'td' as well. Because 'th' already have 200px width. 
And I have added the example values. You can change it according to your requirement. Please try to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```css
        .table {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: red;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        div {
            text-align: right;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class='table'>
        <div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>1111111</div>
            <div>1111111111111</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-align :right  ----> pulls the text into right end

padding-right: 50%  or padding-left : 50% ----> add space from the right or left to center

> use 45 - 49 percentage in padding to make a crisp center alignment depends on your requirement

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18923538273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9823</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```